# Как правильно работает тег <supports-screens>?

Tags: android

В манифесте можно указать такой тег , который как указано делает следующее

> Элемент  определяет разрешение экрана, требуемое для функционирования устройства. Данный тег позволяет указать размеры экран, для которого был спроектировано приложение. Система будет масштабировать ваше приложение на основе ваших макетов на тех устройствах, которые поддерживают указанные вами разрешения экран. Для других случаев система будет растягивать макет по мере возможности.

В конце написано, что экран будет растягиваться, но тогда не понятно, какие ограничение устанавливает данный тег? Ведь и так когда я подготовлю набор файлов для разных экранов, они будут использоваться и при случае, если будет экран подготовленных файлов для которого не найдется то насколько я понимаю система будет пробовать адаптировать экран. Тогда зачем указывать данный тег?

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто: если ты устанавливаешь `false` для больших экранов `android:largeScreens` и `android:xlargeScreens`, то тогда для них применяется **screen compatibility mode**, который ужасным образом растягивает приложение вызывая размытие и пикселизацию.

> Lets you specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable
>   [screen compatibility mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) for screens larger than what your application supports.